# Pimpl idiom with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, oop, pimpl-idiom

I want to use pimpl idiom with inheritance.

Here is the base public class and its implementation class:

```
class A
{
    public:
      A(){pAImpl = new AImpl;};
      void foo(){pAImpl->foo();};
    private:
      AImpl* pAImpl;  
};
class AImpl
{
    public:
      void foo(){/*do something*/};
};
```

And I want to be able to create the derived public class with its implementation class:

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
      void bar(){pAImpl->bar();};    // Can't do! pAimpl is A's private.
};        

class BImpl : public AImpl
{
    public:
      void bar(){/*do something else*/};
};
```

But I can't use pAimpl in B because it is A's private.

So I see some ways to solve it:

1. Create BImpl* pBImpl member in B, and pass it to A with additional A constructor, A(AImpl*).
2. Change pAImpl to be protected (or add a Get function), and use it in B.
3. B shouldn't inherit from A. Create BImpl* pBImpl member in B, and create foo() and bar() in B, that will use pBImpl.
4. Any other way?

What should I choose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class A
{
    public:
      A(bool DoNew = true){
        if(DoNew)
          pAImpl = new AImpl;
      };
      void foo(){pAImpl->foo();};
    protected:
      void SetpAImpl(AImpl* pImpl) {pAImpl = pImpl;};
    private:
      AImpl* pAImpl;  
};
class AImpl
{
    public:
      void foo(){/*do something*/};
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
      B() : A(false){
          pBImpl = new BImpl;
          SetpAImpl(pBImpl);
      };
      void bar(){pBImpl->bar();};    
    private:
      BImpl* pBImpl;  
};        

class BImpl : public AImpl
{
    public:
      void bar(){/*do something else*/};
};
```

Comment: When AImpl and BImpl are in separate .cpp files, I don't think this will work. BImple shouldn't be able to inherit from AImple -- because AImple is an incomplete type in the .cpp where BImple is defined.

Comment: @Enigma22134 Can splitting them into 4 files e.g.  `A.h`, `B.h`, `AImpl.h` and `BImpl.h` solve the issue you mention?

Comment: @javaLover Yeah, but I thought the idea was to hide the implementation details in a cpp. Putting impl's in a header doesn't hide them. Though I suppose will still speed up compile times as the only files including the AImpl.h and BImpl.h are A.cpp and B.cpp

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way from a purely object-oriented-theoretical perspective is to not make BImpl inherit from AImpl (is that what you meant in option 3?). However, having BImpl derive from AImpl (and passing the desired impl to a constructor of A) is OK as well, provided that the pimpl member variable is `const`. It doesn't really matter whether you use a get functions or directly access the variable from derived classes, unless you want to enforce const-correctness on the derived classes. Letting derived classes change pimpl isn't a good idea - they could wreck all of A's initialisation - and nor is letting the base class change it a good idea. Consider this extension to your example:

```
class A
{
protected:
   struct AImpl {void foo(); /*...*/};
   A(AImpl * impl): pimpl(impl) {}
   AImpl * GetImpl() { return pimpl; }
   const AImpl * GetImpl() const { return pimpl; }
private:
   AImpl * pimpl;
public:
   void foo() {pImpl->foo();}


   friend void swap(A&, A&);
};

void swap(A & a1, A & a2)
{
   using std::swap;
   swap(a1.pimpl, a2.pimpl);
}

class B: public A
{
protected:
   struct BImpl: public AImpl {void bar();};
public:
   void bar(){static_cast<BImpl *>(GetImpl())->bar();}
   B(): A(new BImpl()) {}

};

class C: public A
{
protected:
   struct CImpl: public AImpl {void baz();};
public:
   void baz(){static_cast<CImpl *>(GetImpl())->baz();}
   C(): A(new CImpl()) {}
};

int main()
{
   B b;
   C c;
   swap(b, c); //calls swap(A&, A&)
   //This is now a bad situation - B.pimpl is a CImpl *, and C.pimpl is a BImpl *!
   //Consider:
   b.bar(); 
   //If BImpl and CImpl weren't derived from AImpl, then this wouldn't happen.
   //You could have b's BImpl being out of sync with its AImpl, though.
}
```

Although you might not have a swap() function, you can easily conceive of similar problems occurring, particularly if A is assignable, whether by accident or intention. It's a somewhat subtle violation of the Liskov substitutability principle. The solutions are to either:

1. Don't change the pimpl members after construction. Declare them to be `AImpl * const pimpl`. Then, the derived constructors can pass an appropriate type and the rest of the derived class can downcast confidently. However, then you can't e.g. do non-throwing swaps, assignments, or copy-on-write, because these techniques require that you can change the pimpl member. However however, you're probably not really intending to do these things if you have an inheritance hierarchy.
2. Have unrelated (and dumb) AImpl and BImpl classes for A and B's private variables, respectively. If B wants to do something to A, then use A's public or protected interface. This also preserves the most common reason to using pimpl: being able to hide the definition of AImpl away in a cpp file that derived classes can't use, so half your program doesn't need to recompile when A's implementation changes.

Answer (score 1):

I would do (1) because A's privates are or no business for B.

Actually I would not pass it to A as you suggest, because A makes its own in A::A().
Calling `pApimpl->whatever()` from Bis also not appropriate (private **means** private).

Comment: If I create A(AImpl*), it will receive Aimpl* from B, and will not create its own.

Comment: I know that. But A and B should really have their own privates. Thats exactly why they are called 'private'. If B inherits from A without PIMPL B cannot see and use A's privates either, so why should that be any different with PIMPL?

Answer (score 1):

As stefan.ciobaca said, if you really wanted A to be extendable, you'd want `pAImpl` to be protected.

However, your definition in `B` of `void bar(){pAImpl->bar();};` seems odd, as `bar` is a method on `BImpl` and not `AImpl`.

There are at least three easy alternatives that would avoid that issue:

1. Your alternative (3).
2. A variation on (3) in which `BImpl` extends `AImpl` (inheriting the existing implementation of `foo` rather than defining another), `BImpl` defines `bar`, and `B` uses its private `BImpl* pBImpl` to access both.
3. Delegation, in which `B` holds private pointers to each of `AImpl` and `BImpl` and forwards each of `foo` and `bar` to the appropriate implementer.

Answer (score -4):

The correct way is to do (2).

In general, you should probably consider to make all you member variables protected by default instead of private.

The reason most programmers choose private is that they don't think about others who want to derive from their class and most introductory C++ manuals teach this style, in the sense that all the examples use private.

EDIT

Code duplication and memory allocation are undesired side-effects of using the pimp design pattern and cannot be avoided to my knowledge.

If you need to have Bimpl inherit Aimpl and you want to expose a consistent interface to them through A and B, B would also need to inherit A.

One thing you can do to simplify things in this scenario is to have B inherit from A and only change the contructor such that B::B(...) {} creates a Bimpl, and add dispatches for all methods of Bimpl that are not in Aimpl.

Comment: yeah i would go for protected too. but how do you deal with creation of the pimpl? should each class have its own pimpl? or should they share all a same pimpl that resides in the base and which is created by the most derived class, put forward as constructor arguments?

Comment: without thinking about it, i would probably go with a separate pimpl for each derived class. but that requires one dynamic memory allocation for each. could not be desired. but it would probably be the easiest thing to do. not sure how to deal with virtuals in the pimpls though.

Comment: No. The reason most programmers choose private is that they know the meaning of the word "encapsulation"...